# GET to API works in browser, but doesn't with Postman

Tags: docker, kubernetes, postman, skaffold

Setting up a Django API and running it with Skaffold in an Kubernetes environment.

`minikube` is running at the `192.168.99.105`. Navigating to `/api/auth/test/` should just respond with `"Hello World!"` as you see below.

[image]

However, when I try to do the same thing in Postman, I get the following (picture shows `https`, but happens with `http` too).

[image]

Why would this be?

I have `--port-forward` setup so I can still access the API from Postman via `localhost:5000/auth/test/`, so this issue isn't preventing me from getting stuff done.

Comment: The issue in protocol. In browser this is `http` but in Postman it's `https`

Comment: Same whether you try `http` or `https` in Postman. I'm using `nginx-ingress` which I think defaults all traffic to `https` even if it `http://` is what is sent to it. Could that possibly be the issue? Postman is making a request on either `http` or `https`, `ingress-nginx` converts to `https` and there is no certificate in Postman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `SSL certificate verification` set to `OFF`, as follows:

[image: stackoverflow]